# Python: getting the previous item from a list based on closeness

Tags: python

Is there a way to get the previous item in a `list`, based on 'closeness'?  For example:

```
[     Range(start=datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), end=datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0)),
      Range(start=datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0), end=datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0)),
      Range(start=datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0), end=datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 15, 0, 0, 0))]
```

Above is a `list` containing `namedtuple`s (called `Range`), each containing a start date and an end date.

**I know that this can be done in a linear way using loops etc., but I was wondering if it could be done more efficiently?**

*Example input/output*:

If I input `datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0)`, it should return the closest previous start datetime:

```
Range(start=datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), end=datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0))
```

If I input `datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 27, 0, 0, 0)`, it should return the same as above:

```
Range(start=datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), end=datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0))
```

If I input `datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 14, 0, 0, 0)`, it should return:

```
Range(start=datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0), end=datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters had a brainfart then, corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement `__lt__` or `__cmp__` for your `Range` object, you can do:

```
import bisect
position = bisect.bisect_left(range_list, your_input)
if position > 0:    
    nearest_range = range_list[position - 1]
else:
    nearest_range = None
```

This, of course, assumes that your list is already sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Sets are [by definition not ordered](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

You want to use a list or tuple instead, and perhaps make your `Range` objects sortable (implement a [`__cmp__` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__), or use an appropriate key function; see the [Python sorting HOWTO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/)).